# angular-js UI-SELECT is not appearing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ui-select

I've included ui-select js and css in my page :

```
<link href="assets/plugins/ui-select/select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
type="text/css"
<script src="assets/plugins/ui-select/select.min.js" tyle="text/javascript"
</script>
```

I added the ui-select as :

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label>Type <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
    <ui-select ng-model="form.type" theme='bootstrap' close-on-select='false'
               ng-required="true">
        <ui-select-match placeholder='select type'>
            {{$select.selected.value}}
        </ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat='t.id as t in types | filter:$select.search'>
            <div ng-bind-html-unsafe="t.value"></div>
            <small>
                {{t.value}}
            </small>
        </ui-select-choices>
        <ui-select>
</div>
```

in js :

```
angular.module('backOfficeApp)
 .controller('ManagementReportsCtrl, ManagementReportsCtrl);
ManagementReportsCtrl.$inject=['$sce','$scope','$http','$filter'];
function ManagementReportsCtrl($sce,$scope,$http,$filter){
```

AND GET FUNCTION for $scope.types = data;
?
The UI-SELECT  is not appearing in my template, any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add dependency to your module

```
angular.module('backOfficeApp', ['ui.select'])
 .controller('ManagementReportsCtrl, ManagementReportsCtrl);
 ...
```

Comment: The input's appearing as input text not select box with :"{{$select.placeholder}}"(as a placeholder) inside

Comment: You need to assign types to $scope of controller: 

   $scope.types = [{'id': 1, 'value': 'Type 1'}, {'id': 2, 'value': 'Type 2'}];

Comment: I tried that before, same problem I don't know if I'm missing to include a specific js file or something

Comment: Please show somehow full error message from console.